# PHP code being displayed, not interpreted

Tags: php

I recently set up an AWS EC2 instance and installed Apache, PHP, and MySQL on the 64-bit Linux server using yum

Then I uploaded my php files for my contact form in /var/HTML/WWW

It displays fine except parts of my contact form are being displayed. They are PHP— the PHP tags and the code within them are being shown.

Here is a live example: 23.23.152.36

And here is a version on another server [where its working fine](http://www.the-irf.com/contact/index2.php).

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Please post the code, we generally don't like to visit external sites, especially bare IP addrs.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : Okay, I understand. 

Here is a paste that contains the body and PHP of my contact-form: http://www.pastedump.com/paste/2891
or
http://pastebin.com/RqA2VevQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have PHP enabled on your webserver?  For Apache, you may need to modify httpd.conf to enable PHP.

Can you run `phpmyinfo()` on your webserver?

Comment: I didn't remember enabling it, but I guess it is because I ran phpinfo() and it works.

You can see the results here: http://23.23.152.36/info.php

Comment: Try changing `<?php=$name;?>`  to `<?php echo $name;?>`

Comment: Actually you will want to change `<?php=$name;?>` to `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES)?>`  to account for special characters like apostrophe's that may be in the field value.

Comment: I made the change and it gets rid of the value as I wanted, but the form is never emailed to me. :-(

Here is my code with the changes you suggested: http://pastebin.com/rqVTdJ9c

Comment: Are you able to send a test email to yourself using PHP?  Do you need to include an action URL in your form tag?

Comment: Before, when the code was in the form of <?=$name;?> and that did appear in the input-field, when I manually cleared the input-field and filled the form and submited it, an email was sent to me. But when I replaced it with your solution, the email was never sent to me



Currently, there is no action attribute as the php code that interperts the form data and sends the form is in the same file as the html of the form.

Comment: My apologies - forgot a semi-colon.  Try `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES);?>` and see if that helps

Comment: Yes, it did. Bloddy Semi-colons ><  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Enable short_open_tag in you php.ini

```
   short_open_tag
   Default Value: On
   Development Value: Off
   Production Value: Off
```

Comment: I don't want to enable short_open_tags. I want the input fields to be blank yet I need the form to submit properly and email me the results.

Answer (score 1):

shorthand notation is on its way to deprication, i wouldnt suggest building code with shorthand notation anymore.

just use `<?php echo ?>`

Comment: yes, I know that. I don't want to use shorthand notation. I want the input-fields to be blank as in the link to the working-fine example in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change `<?php=$name;?>` to `<?= $name ?>`. That's what you need to do if you want to use the shorthand notation.

Comment: No, i want the input-fields to be blank and the form to still submit correctly and email me the result.